# JS: the document.write method doesn't work with double minus and double plus, why?

Tags: javascript, methods, console.log

I tried:

document.write(15--);
document.write(++15);

and nothing show in the browser... the console gave me a red sentence.. why?

Comment: Red sentence tells you why.

Comment: @Observer I know but I don't know what's the meaning: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation

Comment: You try to decrement a literal value. You only can decrement variables. If you want to write "15--", you need to call `document.write("15--")`

Comment: @Psi wow thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
var number = 15;
++number;
console.log(number);
```